# OnTouchListener on Full Screen not calling

Tags: android

I am using the VideoPlayerView and play the video in FULLSCREEN MODE and add the OnTouchListener. On OnTouchListener on VideoPlayerView is calling in android version 2.3 and not calling on first and even on second attempt in android version 4.0. Please help what could be problem which result to not calling OnTouchListener in android version 4.0

Please help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(currentTime - lastTimeExecution > 2 * 1000) {
        lastTimeExecution = currentTime;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int viewWidth = display.getWidth();

        // RIGHT SIDE SCREEN
        if(event.getX()> (viewWidth*0.7)){
            nextVideo(1);
        }
        else if(event.getX()< (viewWidth*0.3)){
            previousVideo(1);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
};

playerView.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    1.Get resolution of screen 
    2.Set Height & Width of a panel to screen size.
    3.Set video handle to that panel handle
    4.Listen touch event from that panel
```

Comment: Please elaborate this more. How can go through this approach